# Reasons behind Cocoa error code NSFileWriteUnknownError

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, error-handling

We are developing a document-based Objective-C project, using NSPersistentDocument and NSPersistentStore to save a unique binary file on disk. No autosave.

One customer has a recurring saving issue

> The document "something.extension" could not be saved

that we cannot reproduce in our development setup. They can load their saved file without issue, but after a few changes the error pops up when trying to save. In our own setup, using the same build, the file opens and saves without issue.

The error is too vague for us to pinpoint the exact reason why their document would not save, but based on the very basic error message, we have realised the error raised is NSFileWriteUnknownError = 512.

**In which situation would that error be raised? In which situation wouldn't the other, more specific error codes be applicable?**

We build using SDK 10.14 and both us and the customer run on macOS Monterey 12.3.1

**EDITED ON 09/08/22** - Added details based on Willeke's comments.

**EDITED ON 17/08/22** - Underlying error

The error's userInfo comes with an underlying error message, which our customer could display. It states "No known persistent store for URL"

Comment: What is Cocoa's local persistent store?

Comment: [NSPersistentStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstore?language=objc), from Core Data

Comment: Document based app (`NSPersistentDocument`)? Any extra overrides? Is it just one file? Is the customer running macOS Monterey 12.3.1? Which store type? Autosave? How do you know the error number?

Comment: @Willeke Added those details in the post. My question is more general though. It is about why would Cocoa raise an unknown error, wouldn't it be always clear why a file cannot be saved?